# window Location - only protocol, hostname and pathname

Tags: javascript, location, pathname

Say I have this URL:

http://www.domain.com/subpage/?somsearch#somehash?

Is there a standard way to get the following result, without hash and search:

http://www.domain.com/subpage/

**This is how I do it now:**

```
var windowLocation = window.location;
alert(windowLocation.protocol + '//' + windowLocation.hostname + windowLocation.pathname);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Bergi, this is pretty simple:

http://jsfiddle.net/8Vr7n/3/

```
var url = "http://google.com/?search=bob#asdf";

var shorterUrl = url.split("#")[0].split("?")[0];

alert(shorterUrl);
```

Comment: This one won't remove hashes from URIs without a search part.

Comment: @Bergi Ok I changed the fiddle

Comment: uh, I just meant change it to `url.split("?")[0].split("#")[0]` which is much more elegant?

Comment: haha i see, but i think you mean `url.split("#")[0].split("?")[0]`?

Comment: Thanks Mikey, would you say this gives better performance than the example I gave?

Comment: That works fine, I guess i'm just used to .net where you have to have the character in the string or it blows up... thanks

Comment: @Hakan Bergi is right, unless you're doing this a million times or something, don't worry about it